# position and dimension of elements after floating element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I styled an image with float:left, and predictably, the text of the header after it appears to the right of the image (if it helps, the context for this situation is a logo and title next to each other in the header of a website).

When I look at the header element (h1), it takes up space behind the image (overlapping).  The text is still next to the image, but the background of the h1 element overlaps with the image.

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="logo2.png" /></a>
  <h1>AlanHoRizon</h1>
  <p>
...
#header img {
    float: left;
}
```

Is this how floating is supposed to work?  Is background synonymous to the padding in the css box model?  What if I wanted the header element to begin completely after the image, including the background (which is what I expected float to do actually).

Doesn't actually affect the appearance of the header, as everything appears as it should, but I'm curious, as it would add to my understanding of html and css web design.

thanks.

Comment: can you put your code.so i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href=""><img id="logo" src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/abstract" alt="" /></a>
    <div>
        <h1>AlanHoRizon</h1>
        <h3>Site description</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0; 
    line-height: 0;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
}
#header div {
    float: left;
    padding: .25em;
}
```

And here's the [complete jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/xxVjJ/)

Answer (score 0):

modify the css code to:

```
h1
{
float:left;
}
img
{
float:left;
}
```

This should work. The following will produce the heading on the left of the image.

Comment: Interesting, no matter how much I read up on floating, it seems I still don't fully understand how it all works.  Always something new to learn.  What if I wanted to add a site description that goes under the header, but still to the side of the image?  Would this still work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I found an answer to my question.  Simply put, it seems like this is just how floating behavior works.  The content is pushed over, but the background and borders still go behind the float:

http://phrogz.net/CSS/understandingfloats.html#ascolumns

I'm not sure if padding is synonymous to background, but I did test the header elements "padding" simply by making the background color red, and the background indeed is behind the float.  In terms of the css box model, I'm still not quite sure what's going on.